# while making data partition in R i am getting this error

Tags: r, caret

```
Error in createDataPartition(bank_full_train$y, p = 0.75, list = F) : 
  could not find function "createDataPartition"
```

This error i am getting while running the line of code

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run `library(caret)`?

Comment: rlang was in old version and updated was not able to install. I have uninstall it and reinstall and solved. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that it can't find the function. So first make sure you loaded the package by `libary(caret)`. What you can also try is to paste `caret::` before the function like this `caret::createDataPartition`. You can use the following code:

```
library(partition)
library(caret)
train_index <- caret::createDataPartition(bank_full_train$y, p 0.8, list = FALSE)
data_train <- bank_full_train[train_index,]
data_test <- bank_full_train[-train_index,]
```

Please not: We don't have some reproducible data from you, so if this doesn't work, please make sure to create some reproducible data.